# place pull down select menu within a form

Tags: html

I'm builiding a form with several fields, and it is placed in a table to be more easy to read. I want to have a pulldown menu INSIDE THE form, but using the "select/option" tag I always have the pulldown before or after the whole form. How can I do? Here an example:

```
    document.write('name "Addrow" <form action="xxxxxx.php?Mode=ADD" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">')
    document.write('<table width="900"><th width="250"></th><th width="650"></th>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Codice evento:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="text" name="ID_evcls" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Tipo evento:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="text" name="ID_tipoev" maxlength="5" size="10"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Titolo:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="text" name="TitEv" maxlength="35" size="35"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Descrizione:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="text" name="Descr" maxlength="150" size="75"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Data manifestazione:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="date" name="DataEv"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Luogo manifestazione:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="text" name="PlacEv" maxlength="25" size="25"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Nazione:</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="text" name="NatEv" maxlength="3" size="3" value="ITA"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('<TR>')
    document.write('<TD>Immagine da utilizzare (JPEG):</td>')
    document.write('<TD><input type="file" name="userfile"accept="image/jpeg"></td>')
    document.write('</TR>')
    document.write('</table>')
    fn_buildchooseeventclass()
    document.write('<input type="submit" value="Conferma inserimento">')
    document.write('</form>')
}

function fn_buildchooseeventclass() {
    document.write('<select name="carlist" form="Addrow">')
    document.write('<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>')
    document.write('<option value="saab">Saab</option>')
    document.write('<option value="opel">Opel</option>')
    document.write('<option value="audi">Audi</option>')
    document.write('</select>')
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to insert this in a `<tr><td>`

so, if I do it your style:

```
document.write('<TR>');
document.write('<TD>');
fn_buildchooseeventclass();
document.write('</TD>');
document.write('</TR>');
document.write('</table>');
```

Edit: here is working example: http://jsbin.com/axuxiz/1/edit

Some sidenotes: it is considered a bad brad practice to use a `<table>` for layouting four page.
Using `document.write` to create your ui is rather inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and your time, but to me it does not work. Do you have some suggestion to avoid tables? And how to build html pages in Javascript functions without document.write? Again thank you very much.

Comment: @Roberto Alfieri I added a working example in my answer. You can avoid tables by using css, but I have to admit that tables are a quick way to start building website.

Comment: You are mu god! Thank you so very much ciao